# I want to create containerd/config.toml file for local lxc containers

Tags: server, lxc, container, kubernetes

0

I've been trying and looking for a solution to use my local lxc containers images to get loaded in my local k8s cluster.

By this, I have a Dev Environment, which has few lxc containers and images. I have created a cluster with the help of kubeadm, containerd and calico.

Everything is running well so far. I haven't look into networking yet. The problem arises here is that from my deployment the k8 is trying to get the image from docker instead of local storage. Help me out.

I have try this
'''
`/etc/containerd/config.toml [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.lxc"] root_path = "/snap/bin/lxc"`
'''
The error I got when I described the pod

`Pod/lxc-deployment-55df87595f-rdth8   Failed to pull image "nginx-image": failed to pull and     unpack image "docker.io/library/nginx-image:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/nginx-image:latest": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed`

Also when I change

> 'snapshotter = "overlayfs"

to lxc My node gets into NOT READY status.

I have asked this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77285798/i-want-to-create-containerd-config-toml-file-for-local-lxc-containers) aslo.

p.s. I have reasearched this a bit and found that i have to develop a CRI which will interact with k8 cluster directly to run my local LXC images in K8. I would to see some work around. I can't convert my lxc to docker images as it would add unneccassary layer.